# Save data from loop to array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, loops

We want to setText that will display all data from the loop but we aren't able to do so as the setText is only able to save the last int printed by the loop.
We want all the data from the loop that I have provided to be displayed.

Thanks in advance!

```
for(int i=0; i < intArray.length; i++){
    System.out.print(intArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Build a `StringBuffer` and pass its value to the `setText` method

Comment: give info what your `setText ` is?like this is `String` or `Array` add your code first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking you could use the set text like so:

```
 for(int i=0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
     component.setText(comonent.getText() + intArray[i]);
 }
```

However, this is inefficient. As @Fran Montero said, use a string builder:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 for(int i=0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
     sb.append(intArray[i]);
 }
 component.setText(sb.toString());
```